# Change date to Universal Time Format changes my date wrongly I can't get error

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, format

I am trying to simply change the date format from the datatable to universal time format but it formats it wrongly as if I have date for August 7 it changed it to August 8 after formatting it to universal date time. My code for formatting date is,

```
DateVar[runs] = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0])).ToUniversalTime().ToString();
```

Don't get in to code its correct and its a part of loop so "run" is loop and output is data set having one table I have first data in table is "Sunday, August 07, 2011 10:52 PM" and it was converted to "8/8/2011 5:52:00 AM" after implementing universal time format.

Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: What exactly do *you* understand by the phrase "Universal Time Format"? And what's the contents of `output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0]` exactly? (If it's a `DateTime`, why are you converting it to a string first?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run `ToUniversalTime()` from `Greenwich` it will give same time but if i do it while I live some where else it will get an offset date time object of `+ or - hours` depending on position.

Comment: then how can i fix this error ? how would i get the same date time but formated according to Universe Time ??

Answer (score 4):

Universal time isn't a *format* - it's a time zone, effectively. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but converting a "local" `DateTime` to "universal" `DateTime` *will* usually change the time. If you don't want that to happen, don't call `ToUniversalTime`.

It's a pity that the .NET date/time API isn't as clear as it could be - the `DateTime` type itself has some horrible ambiguities about it. I'm trying to improve the situation with my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project, but you will need to understand what time zones are about etc.

Personally I would suggest *not* using simply `DateTime.Parse` or just calling `ToString` unless you're absolutely sure that the default format is what you want. I usually call `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the expected format (and usually `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` unless it's a user-entered string) - and likewise I provide a format string to the `ToString` call.

In your code you're simply converting a string to a string - what are you attempting to accomplish? If you're just trying to change the format (e.g. to `dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm:ss`) then you don't need to call `ToUniversalTime` but you *do* need to provide the format string.

I suggest you split your code out into several statements to help you debug this (and for general code clarity):

- Fetch the string from the `DataTable`, if you really need to (if it's already a `DateTime`, there's no point in converting it to a string and then back again)
- Parse the string (again, assuming you need to)
- Perform any conversions you need to
- Format the `DateTime` with an explicit format string

Now if any single operation is causing a problem, you can isolate it more easily.

Comment: you have written alot i have understud a little bit actually i simply want to parse my date time to universal date time and push it in to array of string type then what should i do my code is in the post above my time zone is GMT -8 pacific (us/canada) ?

Comment: @Syed: What do you *mean* by "parse my date time to universal date time"? And what is the type of `output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0]` to start with? You need to provide more information about what data you've got and what you're trying to get out of it.

Comment: @All i have successfully get what i want and what i change to my code mention above is, ((DateTimeFormatInfo myDTFI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;))                 ((DateVar[runs] = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0]), myDTFI).ToString();))

Comment: @Syed: I *suspect* you're making this *much* harder than you need to. For example, you can use the invariant culture instead of creating a new US culture - and I still very much doubt that you need to convert the data row value to a string, then parse it, then convert it back to a string. You never answered our question of what  type `output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0]` was in the first place...